# error analyse with multi receiver mailmessage

Tags: c#, mailmessage

I have to send mail with multiple receivers. I use a mailmessage object with a "to" property containing semi-colon separated addresses. When i catch exception is there a way to know witch address generate the error?

I know i can use a loop but i think that way is more efficient for big address list and attached files.

I use the code below :

```
MailMessage message = new MailMessage();
        message.From = new MailAddress(txtDe.Text);
        message.Bcc.Add(mails);
        message.Body = CKEditor1.Text;
        message.IsBodyHtml = true;
        message.BodyEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
        message.Subject = txtObj.Text;
        message.SubjectEncoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;

        string txt=Regex.Replace(CKEditor1.Text, @"<[^>]*>", String.Empty);
        var plainView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(txt, null, "text/plain");

        var htmlView = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(CKEditor1.Text, null, "text/html");
        message.AlternateViews.Add(plainView);
        message.AlternateViews.Add(htmlView);

        string[] foldersIds = Session["uploadedFoldersId"].ToString().Split(new char[] { '|' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

        foreach (string folderId in foldersIds)
        {
            string tempPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { Path.GetTempPath(), "_AjaxFileUpload", folderId });

            DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);
            FileInfo[] files = di.GetFiles();

            smtp.attachement[] att = new smtp.attachement[files.Length];

            foreach (FileInfo f in files)
            {
                message.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(f.FullName));
            }
        }
        try
        {
            client.Send(message);
            message.Dispose();

            Response.Redirect(tools.urlRetour(Request.QueryString["retour"]));
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            err.setErreur("Erreur à l'envoi!", ex.ToString(), 0);
            if (last) displayInfo();
        }

        finally
        {
            if (last)
            {
                foreach (string folderId in foldersIds)//remove temporary uploaded files folders
                {
                    string tempPath = Path.Combine(new string[] { Path.GetTempPath(), "_AjaxFileUpload", folderId });

                    DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(tempPath);
                    di.Delete(true);
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I read correctly from documentation (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.smtpfailedrecipientsexception(v=vs.110).aspx) you should be able to read failed addresses from FailedRecipient property of Exception. To get proper type of exception, change your catch block to handle SmtpFailedRecipientsException kind of exceptions.

```
catch (SmtpFailedRecipientsException smtpSendException)
{
 err.setErreur(smtpSendException.FailedRecipient...);
}
```

Comment: That's right but you have to use SmtpFailedRecipientException with no s and it work thanks